# Interpretation of Youden's J Statistic

Tags: classification, roc

Youden's J statistic is defined as J = sensitivity + specificity - 1, and is equal to the vertical distance between the chance line and the ROC curve for a classifier. I'm having trouble describing the meaning of this value in an intuitive way. It has been described (on Wikipedia and corresponding paper by Powers 2011  "Evaluation: From Precision, Recall and F-Score to ROC, Informedness, Markedness & Correlation") as a measure of "informedness," i.e. probability of an informed decision (as opposed to a random guess). What does it mean to make an "informed decision?" Is an "informed" decision just one that is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informedness is the probability that a decision is informed rather than a guess - basically it compensates for prevalence and bias.

In practice (as illustrated in the cited paper) it corresponds to a system that gives a correct decision Inf% of the time and an random or chance decision the rest of the time.